# How to make tasks in boost::asio thread pool Cancelable/Interruptable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, threadpool, boost-asio

I have a thread pool made with `boost::asio::io_service` from recipe like [this](http://think-async.com/Asio/Recipes). I wonder how to interrupt posted into it tasks (not killing threads), so that they would be replaced with next tasks in pool?

Answer (score 1):

Callbacks in boost::asio in general should be reasonably fast. They should just do some work, schedule another one and finish. This will be the points, where task looses CPU and other task will be taken into execution.

There are `boost::thread::interrupt()` and `boost::thread_group::interrupt_all()`, but they could stop execution thread only at *interruption points*. The interruption will be seen as exception `boost::thread_interrupted`. This means, that you have to handle exception somehow and in your case - release current task. It is much more complicated, than just doing one step of processing and scheduling handler for the rest.

Moreover, you could play with `interrupt()` and `interrupt_all()` in threads which do execute your own routine, while this is not the case for threads running `io_service::run()`. One can imagine, that `boost::thread_interrupted` is being thrown inside `run()` method, instead of async handler, which could end with unexpected behavior.